# PHPExcel time 12:00 showing as 1021260:00:00 when try to edit

Tags: php, codeigniter, time, phpexcel

In my PHPExcel I am showing time field and it is showing perfectly. My issue is

**At the time of display, it seems ok. But if I double click on the field, then the time `12:00` shows like `1021260:00:00`**

How can I solve this? The time conversion code is given below

```
$date = '2016-07-01 12:00:00';
$this -> excel -> getActiveSheet() -> setCellValue('G1', PHPExcel_Shared_Date::PHPToExcel(strtotime($date)));
$this -> excel -> getActiveSheet() -> getStyle('G1') -> getNumberFormat() -> setFormatCode(PHPExcel_Style_NumberFormat::FORMAT_DATE_TIME3);
```

**At the generation time**

[image]

**After double click**

[image]

Comment: writing for excel 2007 and editing with excel 2007 ?

Comment: @Bob0t, I am writing it as `excel5` with `.xls` format and editing with excel 2003, 2007

Comment: is the cell defined as number and not automatic ? I mean using something like : `$activeSheet->setCellValueExplicit('G1', PHPExcel_Shared_Date::PHPToExcel(strtotime($date)), PHPExcel_Cell_DataType::TYPE_NUMERIC);`

Comment: @Bob0t, the cell defined as `hh:mm` format in excel and while checking the excel sheet also it shows the same.

Comment: it should be `h:mm` and DataType is such a mad thing really :p double check this :D

Comment: @Bob0t, Yeah it is `h:mm`(`FORMAT_DATE_TIME3`). Its a typo. :)

Comment: Do you want it only `h:mm` format?

Comment: @Poonam, I would like to show it in `hours:minutes` format and this is the format provided by `PHPExcel`. Is there a way?

Comment: Actually I got same problem.. then i used `FORMAT_DATE_XLSX22` for `'m/d/yy h:mm'` format

Comment: I tried with the same and it works fine. The only bug is with the `h:mm` format. Thank you for the help @Poonam

Answer (score 0):

Its using a epoch timestamp
chech this page to convert: http://www.epochconverter.com/
Maby this helps you.

Kind regards

Comment: I need a way to fix the behavior of PHP excel library. Not in common php